# What word best represents the concept of data that can be easily used by a computer?

Tags: adjectives, computing, concept

I want to find a word that encapsulates the concept of information that can be easily parsed by a computer and does not require a human to interpret the concepts.

Imagine you are filling out a form at your doctors office.  One section is for describing your illness.  One form may have a large blank area for you to write a paragraph describing your symptoms in sentences.  Another form may have check boxes with predefined symptoms and you select those to best describe your illness and assign numbers to indicate how bad that symptom is.  The form with check boxes and numbers is easily parsed by a computer, the form with a blank text area requires the computer to understand your language and also understand the concepts of your illness.

What word describes the data that comes from these two forms?  The form with check boxes provides data that is not open to interpretation and is better for computer processing.  The form with the open field for using natural language is loose and open to interpretation and probably requires human interaction.  I feel like there is a word that a data scientist would use to describe the quality or accuracy of the data. The best I can think of is objective.

Comment: [Computer friendly](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/computer-friendly)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data which is easily understood by computers is often called 'structured' data as opposed to 'unstructured'.

Nicely put on [bright planet](https://brightplanet.com/2012/06/structured-vs-unstructured-data/) website:

> For the most part, structured data refers to information with a high degree of organization, such that inclusion in a relational database is seamless and readily searchable by simple, straightforward search engine algorithms or other search operations; whereas unstructured data is essentially the opposite. The lack of structure makes compilation a time and energy-consuming task. It would be beneficial to a company across all business strata to find a mechanism of data analysis to reduce the costs unstructured data adds to the organization.

Answer (score 0):

Parsable.

Source: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/parsable, https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/parsable, computer engineer.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another common term for this is *machine readable*.

From Wikipedia:

> Machine-readable data is data (or metadata) in a format that can be easily processed by a computer.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine-readable_data